# Использование sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, kotlin

есть приложение под android, в нем класс Sharedpref

```
class Sharedpref private constructor(context: Context) : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("main", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun getToken (): Boolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("USER_TOKEN_KEY", false)

    fun saveToken(token: Boolean) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("USER_TOKEN_KEY", token).apply()
    }

    fun prefClear() {
        sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply()
    }

    fun saveName(name: String, value: String) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(name, value).apply()
    }

    fun getName(name: String, value: String): String? = sharedPreferences.getString(name, value)

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: Sharedpref? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): Sharedpref {

            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(Sharedpref::class.java) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE = Sharedpref(context)
                    }
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }
}
```

и вызов метода в активити

```
private fun triggers() {

    val pref = Sharedpref.getInstance(baseContext)

    if (pref.getToken()) {
        textView!!.text = "Приложите телефон к метке"
    } else {
        textView!!.text = "Пожалуйста, выполните вход"
    }
}
```

падает с ошибкой  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean с указанием на строчки

`fun getToken (): Boolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("USER_TOKEN_KEY", false)`

и

```
 if (pref.getToken()) {
```

Comment: ваш класс наследуется от AppCompatActivity?

Comment: да, и Sharedpref и тот, в котором вывзываю

Comment: есть какой то скрытый смысл в таком наследовании?

Comment: да в общем то нет, скорее всего копипастнула и забыла потом просто)

Comment: вы же понимаете что такая забывчивость подтянула вам в класс большое количество кода суперкласса и созданных им объектов, не говоря уже о том, что это системный компонент завязанный на жизненный цикл

Comment: Мда, наследование от Activity с Context в конструкторе и еще синглтон. Жесткий набор антипаттернов :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что у вас в коде нигде не происходит записи строки по этому ключу.

Сейчас то у вас коде сохранение/чтение как `bool`, да. Но, вполне вероятно, во время тестов вы по этому ключу записали строку.

Comment: да, было такое в предыдущей сборке. Ребилднуть просто? или что-то еще сделать?

Comment: @Ксения ребилд не поможет. Нужно сначала удалить с устройства старый билд.

Comment: Ну или удалить этот ключ при старте приложения.